# Symfony3 registering exception listener

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.2

I have a Stripe exception wrapper for all of the exceptions that Stripe might throw based on certain cases. I'm trying to register an event listener for that exception being thrown, but it doesn't seem like the listener is ever fired.

Instead of returning the event in a json response, the exception throws a 500 and renders the stack trace. Is there something that I'm missing?

```
// AppBundle/Exceptions/StripePaymentException.php
namespace AppBundle\Exceptions;

use Exception;

class StripePaymentException extends Exception {

    public $response;
    public $message;

    public function __construct($message, $response, $code = 0, Exception $previous = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($message, $code);

        $this->message = $message;
        $this->response = $response;
    }

    public function getResponse()
    {
        return $this->$response;
    }

}

// AppBundle/EventListener/StripePaymentExceptionListener.php
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;

class StripePaymentExceptionListener
{
    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        $exception = $event->getException();
        $data = $exception->getResponse();
        $response = new JsonResponse($data);
        $event->setResponse($response);
    }
}

// services.yml
app.stripe_payment_exception_listener:
class: AppBundle\EventListener\StripePaymentExceptionListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, priority: 200 }
```

Comment: Which error exactly do you retrieve?

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri So the exception gets thrown, but it doesn't get formatted in the way I'm expecting it (through the listener). It's throwing a 500 and rendering a new page instead of just returning a response.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the `priority` setting on your custom listener. If you have another listener that is being fired *before* then this will never actually be what returns the Exception.

You could change the `priority` here:

```
// services.yml
app.stripe_payment_exception_listener:
class: AppBundle\EventListener\StripePaymentExceptionListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, priority: 1 }
```

Or alternatively you could alter your "standard" ExceptionListener to fork based on the type of exception caught:

```
if(instanceof $exception STRIPE_EXCEPTION_CLASS)
    $data = $exception->getResponse();
    $response = new JsonResponse($data);
    $event->setResponse($response);
}
else {
    //"normal" behavior here
}
```

... or based on the type of `Accept` Header

```
//if you're accepting json, return json
if( $accept->has('application/json') ) {
    $response = new Response(json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    $event->setResponse($response);
}
//if accepting xml, return xml..
elseif( $request->isXmlHttpRequest() ) {
    $xml = new \SimpleXMLElement('<exception/>');
    $data = array_flip($data);
    array_walk_recursive($data, array ($xml, 'addChild'));
    $response = new Response($xml->asXML());
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8');
    $event->setResponse($response);
}
```

Comment: I've tried changing the priority. When I run `php bin/console debug:event-dispatcher kernel.exception`, the StripePaymentExceptionListener is the first one in terms of order. However, it doesn't seem to be hitting the listener at all when the exception is thrown (tried placing xdebug breakpoints and var_dump, but neither works).

Comment: Have you tried adding a `return` statement after `setResponse` is called?